# sort and binary_search on array of struct

Tags: c++, sorting, binary-search

here's my code

```
typedef struct Data{
    int date;
    string currency;
    string exchange;
    float low;
    float high;
    long long int daily_cap;
}Data;

bool comp2(const Data *data1, const Data *data2){
        return (data1->date < data2->date);
}

bool comp1(Data *data1, Data *data2){
    if (data1->date != data2->date)
        return (data1->date < data2->date);
    if (data1->currency != data2->currency)
        return (data1->currency < data2->currency);
    else
        return (data1->exchange < data2->exchange);
}

int main()
{
    ifstream infile("test.txt");
    Data tmp;
    vector<Data*> P_data;

        while (infile){
        Data *tmp = new Data();
        infile >> tmp->date;
        infile >> tmp->currency;
        infile >> tmp->exchange;
        infile >> tmp->low;
        infile >> tmp->high;
        infile >> tmp->daily_cap;
        P_data.push_back(tmp);
    }

    sort(P_data.begin(), P_data.end(), comp1);

//  bool yes = binary_search(P_data.begin()+1, P_data.end(), 20140212, comp2);

    int c = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<= 20; ++i){
        cout << P_data[i]->date << " " << P_data[i]->exchange << " " << c << endl;
        c++;
    }

}
```

the first question is that why after sorting,

the first line will be

```
-842150451  0
```

and the second line start sorting

```
20130101 Wii 0 ....
```

and the second question is binary_search

Is there anything wrong in my code ?

the error message show that

bool(const Data*, const Data*)  can't convert arg1  'const int'  to  'const Data*'

Answer (score 0):

1. Regarding the printing of the first line, it might be that the first element, i.e. `P_data[0]` is wrongfully initialized (perhaps to random values) which would make the element have a random `int` as `date` and an empty string as `exchange`.
2. The error you're receiving is when giving `binary_search`(http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/binary_search/) a value of `20140212` instead of a `Data` object which contains that date (I'm guessing you want to find the object which this date.

You should modify your search code to:

```cpp
// Create a temp variable which target date
Data tmp;
tmp.date = 20140212;

// Search for it
bool yes = binary_search(P_data.begin()+1, P_data.end(), &tmp, comp2);
```

Also, you might want to consider changing `date` property to `unsigned` to avoid weird negative values.

Answer (score -1):

Can you please post ALL of your code?
Currently your structure's pointer isn't memory allocated, and we can't get the same result as you without all your code.

> the error message show that
>
> bool(const Data*, const Data*) can't convert arg1 'const int' to 'const Data*'

should appear cause you may pass an 'const int' instead of a 'const Data *' to your function.

Comment: I think this is more suitable for the comment section.

Comment: I agree with you, despite I've not actually earned enough reputation to post comment. But I want to help him, I'll remove this answer this afternoon, to be sure he readed it. @t.m